# Upload multiple folders to Azure storage blobs though a gui?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a Azure storage account (blob), that i need to upload an excisting 2000+ folders into (folders with files in each of them). I have downloaded the Azure Storage Explorer, but it only seems to support uploading one folder at a time.

Any ideas or other apps i could use, that supports this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have downloaded the Azure Storage Explorer, but it only seems to
>   support uploading one folder at a time.

While it is true that by clicking on `Upload Folder` button in the UI you can only upload one folder at a time but you can drag multiple folders from your computer and drop them and Storage Explorer will upload those folders.

If you're looking for an alternative to Storage Explorer, please check out [`Cerebrata Cerulean`](https://www.cerebrata.com). It's not free though :). Disclosure: I am building this tool.